# Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound call SQL function

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hi have this problem when executing the calling to my SQL funcion.

This is the code to call the Function

```
CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall("{call OMV_CREAR_INTERACCION(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");          
        // Parametros del procedimiento almacenado
        cst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(objSite));
        cst.setString(2, titulo);
        cst.setString(3, "CRM");
        cst.setString(4, "");
        cst.setString(5, razon1);
        cst.setString(6, razon2);
        cst.setString(7, razon3);              
        // Ejecuta el procedimiento almacenado
        cst.execute();
```

But when execute that, appear in the console this:

```
Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
Exception in thread "RsSp" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at enviaSmsPortDonante.EnviaSMSPortDonante.interaccion(EnviaSMSPortDonante.java:327)
    at enviaSmsPortDonante.EnviaSMSPortDonante.run(EnviaSMSPortDonante.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And this is the SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OMV_CREAR_INTERACCION(p_site_objid IN NUMBER,
                                              p_titulo     IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_origen     IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_notas      IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_reason_1   IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_reason_2   IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_reason_3   IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_resultado  OUT VARCHAR2)
```

Can you help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have 8 placeholers in your function.

```
{call OMV_CREAR_INTERACCION(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
```

And you are providing only 7 parameters via `setXXX()`.

So you have to pass 8th parameter to `cst`.

And you are also getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. So you have to check whether `objSite` is not null and has value in following statement.

```
cst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(objSite));
```

**Update1**

```
CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall("{call OMV_CREAR_INTERACCION(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");          
cst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(objSite));
cst.setString(2, titulo);
cst.setString(3, "CRM");
cst.setString(4, "");
cst.setString(5, razon1);
cst.setString(6, razon2);
cst.setString(7, razon3);
cst.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);//out parameter for p_resultado     
cst.execute();

//to get out parameter
String str = cst.getString(8);
```

Comment: Sorry was a mistake to copy.

the 8th parameter is the response.

cst.execute();
String responsecst.getString(8);
System.out.println(RES.INTERACCION: response);

And objSite is not null because now this parameter is manual, now is 1234

Thanks